# AS3 only render nearby objects

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I'm developing a game that includes walking in a big world with random objects around such as trees, rocks etc'

Now my goal is not to let the total amount of objects in the world to affect the speed of the game..
That's why I thought that maybe I should have an array of objects,
Each object will have its own position,
Then just use a loop to check which ones are near / far
Then use addChild/removeChild respectively 
I still believe that this approach will be a problem though because constantly going through an array with a ton of objects isn't so nice..

So I thought I'd ask you guys.. How would you approach this task?
And code examples would very much be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect you will need some data structure, e.g. [octree/quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree), depending your world is 2D or 3D, which will be filled at world generation phase with all your static objects. Anything dynamic (monsters, etc) will move through the nodes of this tree on their own, and for the display you just use a radius approach, rendering (displaying) only those objects that are in a certain tree-cells distance from the player. With this approach, you will only need to alter display list when your player crosses the border between tree cells, you do a `removeChild()` on all those objects that are in tere cells now too far, and `addChild()` on those that are now in display range.

Edit: Even better, you can have a 2D array containing lists of objects that are in your world, with their actual positions etc, so instead of variable granularity the quadtree offers you will have a uniform grid with each cell of it capable of holding more than a single object. This grid is traversable with more ease than a quadtree, as it naturally holds adjacent element's position, which is needed the most when your player moves continuously through the grid. An example, which is mostly pseudocode, but can give you a hint on what the actual grid looks like:

```
class World {
    var GRID:Vector.<Vector.<Vector.<GameObject>>>; // the grid
    const GRAN:int=100; // this many x this many is one GRID cell
    var gridWidth:int;
    var gridHeight:int;
    public function World(w:int,h:int) { // size in pixels, for example. This depends on how you display objects
        gridWidth=1+Math.floor(w/GRAN);
        gridHeight=1+Math.floor(h/GRAN);
        GRID=new Vector.<Vector.<Vector.<GameObject>>>(gridWidth,true); // fixed size, it optimizes performance
        var i:int; var j:int;
        for (i=0;i<gridWidth;i++) {
            GRID[i]=new Vector.<Vector.<GameObject>>(gridHeight,true); // again fixed size
            for (j=0;j<gridHeight;j++) GRID[i][j]=new Vector.<GameObject>(); 
            // ^ variable size, as initially the world is empty, and it will get 
            //filled with stuff dynamically. But we need to allocate the data structure
        }
    }
    public function PlaceObject(ob:GameObject):void {
        // puts an object into grid and assigns it grid position to refer the grid
        var gx:int=Math.floor(ob.x/GRAN);
        var gy:int=Math.floor(ob.y/GRAN);
        ob.gridX=gx;
        ob.gridY=gy;
        GRID[gx][gy].push(ob);
        // error control is absent, but should be.
    }
    public function MoveObject(ob:GameObject):void {
        // called if game engine moves an object. It has its X&Y changed, but grid position must be updated
        var gx:int=Math.floor(ob.x/GRAN);
        var gy:int=Math.floor(ob.y/GRAN);
        if ((ob.gridX==gx)&&(ob.gridY==gy)) return; // this object didn't leave its grid node
        GRID[ob.gridX][ob.gridY].splice(GRID[ob.gridX][ob.gridY].indexOf(ob),1);
        // will break if the object is not in GRID, so integrity check is needed here
        ob.gridX=gx;
        ob.gridY=gy;
        GRID[gx][gy].push(ob);
    }       
    ...
}
```

Etc. Outside of this class you place a renderer that has player's GRID position, and grabs data from GRID by a specified radius, and places objects into display list.

Comment: I thought of this approach while not knowing about those data structures , but how do I actually go for doing this in code? And wouldn't it still be memory consuming to constantly look for nearby objects in those nodes ?

Comment: Well, any algorithm is a trade-off, either have more memory but less computing time, or vice-versa. This algorithm will net you use a lot of memory (depending on the world size and granuarity), but will seriously shorten time of display list repopulation. Your initial algorithm that involves traversing all the objects in the main list takes the least extra space (you still need the list) but consumes a lot more time per call. You choose. I estimate your 2D tree will not be too big, 64k nodes tops (256x256), which will eat up ~2 MBytes of memory - nothing by today's standards.

Comment: Hi again, firstly thanks for directing me and giving me this solution, it really sounds like this is what I need but I kept looking for information about how to achieve this in AS3 and I didn't even find one place that could someone help a noob like myself do this, I understand the concept of it I'm just not too sure how to achieve this in AS3..

Comment: You know, an actual quad tree might even be an overkill, as you don't need to have a "bucket" of fixed size in your calculations, you can do with any number of objects within a certain node, you just need to lessen its average. So, make a normal 2D array of flat coordinates, and store a list of your objects references in it, then traverse your array by indexes based on player's location and add/remove like with a quad tree.

Comment: Oh I get it, well I suppose I'll try the simpler array version and if it will be slow I'll just go for the quad tree, I read some more about it and got to understanding of how I'll need to create it anyway. so with the array way, will it just be as simple as adding a value to it like so? myArray[x10y20] = new Tree(10,20); ? or is there a better way?

Comment: With an array you plain don't need quadtrees. An array is a "simplified" form of a quad tree, that might be better suited for your purpose. And to fill that array with objects, use the approach I demonstrated, store an array of depth 3, two outer levels are X and Y, so using syntax `theArray[x][y]` you reach the inner list, and you can operate that one with `push()`,`indexOf()` and other array functions.

Comment: That's really great, thank you so much. I'll surely give this a try! I understand the whole idea of this but as a noob AS3 programmer I'd love to get a bit of information about this : GRID:Vector.<Vector.<Vector.<GameObject>>>; I understand it means that Grid is a vector type, but the rest is quite odd haha, is it correct syntax?

Comment: Yes, a vector of vectors is a 2D strongly typed array, a vector of these is also valid. Treat these as your common Arrays in all aspects except type control. You can try using `Array` class, but you will have to manually control index assignment, so that `theArray[10][20]` will return a proper value, and not an undefined or an error.

Comment: Sorry for all of those questions haha, but I suppose it'll be helpeful for whoever looks for that kind of stuff anyway.. what does this line do? GRID[i]=new <Vector.<Vector.<GameObject>>(gridHeight,true); I don't see what the true is for and why you entered the gridHeight

Comment: Nevermind, I understand it's the constructors of the Vector, I read in the API~ One for the length of the vector, one for it to be a fixed size like you commented. there's a syntax issue in your code though, remove the < that comes right after "new", also Math instead of math :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need your objects to persist when they're out of 'view' you can generate them at the outer extent of the player's view distance so that you're only ever looping through active objects. When objects get a certain distance away from the player they get removed.
If you want your objects to persist you could use some system to determine if an object needs to be updated; For example you could give each object a 'zone' property. Objects in the player's zone and in zones adjacent to the player's zone get updated. Those that aren't adjacent, don't need to be updated.

Comment: Actually for the 'Zone' system to work, the objects would need to be assigned to a particular Zone, depending on their position. Check the player's Zone and the adjacent Zones for Objects and push them into an Array that you loop through and update.